# how to know in wcf service in key/value pair

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
//IService.cs

[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
String CheckAuth(String AccountID, String Password);

//Service.cs

  public String CheckAuth(String AccountID, String Password)
{

   String message="";

    string StrCon = @"my conn string";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(StrCon);
    string qry = "select * from Account where AccountID='" + AccountID + "' and Password='"+Password+"'";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        message = "Authorized";

    }
    else
    {
        message = "unauthorized";
    }
    con.Close();


    return message;
}
```

i want to know that what does the variable d: stands for and how can i change the d: to Message:..??

i need some suggestion thank you..

```
//GETTING output 
{
d: "Authorized"
}

//expected output
{
Message: "Authorized"
}
```

i m new to wcf so it will be helpful if i get undertandable suggestion 
thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The variable `d` is there for [security](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/) reasons.
But you can always return an `object` instead of a `string`

```
public object CheckAuth(String AccountID, String Password)
{
    // .. snip

    return new {
       Message = message
    };
}
```

If you call your service like this, it should return something like

```
{ 
    "d" : {
       "Message": "Authorized"
    }
}
```

Not sure what you're using on the front-end, if you use jQuery you could make a wrapper around the ajax function:

```
function doAjax(url, data, cb) {
    $.ajax({
       url: url,
       data: data,
       success: function(data) {
          cb(data.d);
       }
    });
}
```

and make use of your new defined function like this:

```
doAjax('/CheckAuth', yourDataObj, function result(data) {
    console.log(data.Message);
});
```

Comment: my front end is asp.net c# for android and iphone

Comment: return new {
       Message: message
    };  
still shows error in this above code

Comment: Sorry it must have been `return new { Message = message };`